# Implementing SQLite in a Windows 8 app using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, microsoft-metro

I am creating an application that requires local database support (because I don't know how to write and connect a web service). I am developing in VB.NET because it is the only programming language that I have experience with.

I seem to have correctly added SQLite to my application; but I have no idea how to create a database, create tables, create columns and set properties. My understanding is that this all must be done with code, would it be possible to get some guidance and example code on how to do this?

Beyond this I need to know how to add user inputted data, display that data to the user, allow the user to edit the data and allow the user to delete entries. Again I am looking for coded examples with an explanation if possible.

I know that this is a large and complex question but I have searched high and low and nearly every article is written for C# which I cannot make any sense of at all.

Comment: I suggest you use a GUI tool for SQLite to help you in creating and maintaining a database file, and only use the SQLite library in your application to insert, update and select data as part of your program logic. Google for "free sqlite gui". There are plenty to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Google spits out a bunch of examples:
[SQLite in VB.net](http://www.kirupa.com/net/sqllite_vb_pg1.htm)
[Getting SQLite Working with VB.NET](http://orbisvitae.com/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=42215)
[SQLite.NET](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Providers/sqlite-net-provider)
[SQL In VB.NET](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/code/216920/sql-in-vb.net)
[Simple VB.Net Sqlite Example](http://sqlitedev.blogspot.de/2006/09/simple-vbnet-sqlite-example.html)
[SQLite Visual Basic tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitevb/)
[Connecting SQLite with VB.net](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/37438-Connecting-SQLite-with-VB-net.aspx)